# jGit usage on Android device

Tags: android, git, jgit

I'm trying to execute jGit library on Android device. I want to create local repository.

That code is working on PC:

```
File fRepositoryDir = new File("D:/My/jgittestrpo");
if (!fRepositoryDir.exists()) {
    fRepositoryDir.mkdirs();
}

Repository localRepo;
Git git;
try {
    localRepo = new FileRepository(fRepositoryDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/.git");
    localRepo.create();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That same code on Android device not working:

```
File fRepositoryDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "repository");
//File fRepositoryDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "repository");    // Trying on sd card, not working too
if (!fRepositoryDir.exists()) {
    fRepositoryDir.mkdirs();
}

Repository localRepository;
try {
    localRepository = new FileRepository(fRepositoryDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + ".git");
    //localRepository = new FileRepository("/data/data/com.examplecompany.gitexample/files/repository/.git");           // Trying to set repo folder directly
    localRepository.create();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception on Android device:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.examplecompany.gitexample, PID: 2036
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/eclipse/jgit/internal/storage/file/ObjectDirectory
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:159)
    at com.examplecompany.gitexample.MainActivity.onLoginClick(MainActivity.java:173)
    ... 14 more
```

Where is problem? May be i using incorrect library?

Comment: Do you have git installed on our android device? i dont thing so.

Comment: No, i have no git installed on Android device... What steps must be taken to create local repository on Android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some android clients for Git.

Here is a partial list of those tools:

- https://github.com/rtyley/agit
- https://github.com/sheimi/SGit

Another application from the marketplace:

- http://pocketgit.com/
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.pocketgit&hl=en

Comment: Im sorry but there is nothing you can do. Git only shipped on win/unix/mac etc. not for mobile platforms.

Comment: Thanks for explanation)

Comment: It can be done! At least to some degree, a simple Google search reveals "Agit"...

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. Git checkout from android tablet over git+ssh protocol works for me with jgit 3.7.1.201504261725-r. I see similar errors with jgit 4+ though, probably jgit 4+ uses some Java API (NIO.2 ?) not supported on android.

Comment: FYI SGit is no longer maintained. I briefly took over as maintainer and now am continuing development in my fork called MGit (https://github.com/maks/MGit)

Comment: Termux has git.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done! Look at the source code of the [agit application](https://github.com/rtyley/agit) which provides a git-client for Android.

I didn't review it closely, but it seems to use a patched version of JGit and a different implementation of the Repository class to avoid the direct file access which is not possible on Android.

And it likely has some limitations, i.e. no commit/write support for now, but at least it can show how it the basic access is possible and likely you can build it out from there if you need more features.